# Regex to match second word or the first occurance of the another word

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a situation where I need to parser the below content

```
Some Text
Some Text
SUB-TOTAL          :    $0.90 
Some Text          :    $0.79-
SUB-TOTAL          :    $0.11 
TAX                :    $0.05 
TOTAL      $0.16
```

I need to parse till last 'SUB-TOTAL' if `Tax` does not exist, else it has to parse till `TAX`
I am not sure where I did wrong in the regex    *** .*?(?=(TAX|(SUB-TOTAL.*?SUB-TOTAL))) ***
Since have less experience on regex. Can some one please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your regex searches for any single character `.?` that is followed by either the string `TAX` or `SUB-TOTAL`-one-optional-character-`SUB-TOTAL`. Now you don't have that second version, so it will basically return you the newline before the word `TAX`! A `.*` gives you any number of any character and `?:` is non-capturing group (`?=` is lookahead.)

Comment: This may be a misinterpretation of your needs, but if the appropriate code is modifiable, it would probably be better design to parse the text as it is, and then put the logic for ignoring tax **after** the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get up-to and including SUB-TOTAL or TAX with its value, you can use: `.*(?:(?:SUB-TOTAL|TAX)[^\n]*)`... Is that the right cut-off?

**EDIT** OK - made my head hurt... but to get last SUB-TOTAL if it exists, otherwise TAX:

```
^(?:(?:(?!.*SUB-TOTAL.*).*TAX[^\n]*)|(?:.*SUB-TOTAL[^\n]*))
```

Hope this works in your regex engine!

**EDIT2** This version does not return the SUB-TOTAL/TAX line

```
^(?:(?:(?!.*SUB-TOTAL.*).*(?=TAX))|(?:.*(?=SUB-TOTAL)))
```

Comment: Captain, Thanks for the quick response.


Some cases we will have two 'SUB-TOTAL' in that case it should match the second 'SUB-TOTAL'. Some case we will have one 'SUB-TOTAL' which should match the first one, also we have a case where we will NOT have 'SUB-TOTAL' in that case it should match till 'TAX'

Comment: Hi @user_in, regular expressions are generally greedy... so this will match from the start to the end of the line that contains the last occurrence of either SUB-TOTAL or TAX.

Comment: Hi @Captain,
Yes, the given problem is a mix of greedy and non greedy. Do we have any ways to achieve this in regex?

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused... you say to last SUB-TOTAL or to TAX... Is TAX after SUB-TOTAL like in the example? Then this answer gives you exactly that.

Comment: Hi @Captain, yes 'TAX' will always after 'SUB-TOTAL'. 'TAX' Will be always present in the content. 'SUB-TOTAL' is optional, if present it will be one time and in some cases its present two times (as given in the above example). What I am looking is Case-1: only one 'SUB-TOTAL' present it has to match only that and ignore 'TAX'. Case-2: If two 'SUB-TOTAL' present it has to match the second one and ignore the first 'SUB-TOTAL' and 'TAX'. Case-3: If only 'TAX' present, it has to match 'TAX'

Comment: Hi @Captain, Thanks for the solution. Looks to be working. But its still selecting the entire line (example:SUB-TOTAL          :    $0.11), also it not stopping @ start of the 'SUB-TOTAL' or 'TAX', its including/selecting those words as well.